# Page redirect having data from previous page in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am working on front end project having html javascript and angular js.In that i have only one index page , where there every other html will be loaded in div tag when hash change.

```
<div ng-app="mainApp">
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>
```

But the problem is , data loaded in previous page is still in current page after redirecting with new page or pressing back button , it is not clearing.When I reload the current page then only the old page is removing and loading the respective page data.  In index.html I tried this to remove table loaded from some each page , its removing table when the page change

```
window.onhashchange = function() {

            if (document.getElementById("table") != null) {
                var tbl = document.getElementById("table");
                tbl.parentNode.removeChild(tbl);
            }
        }
```

But remaining html elements from the previous page is not removing ,How can I load the page content rewspectively without previous page data.I am using window.location="#newpage" for redirecting

Answer (score 0):

For effective hash management, you should use the angular router or angular UI-router. Using this you can set HTML template and corresponding business logic for each route(hash). It will be something like this

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "main.htm",
        controller : "mainCtrl"
    })
    .when("/red", {
        templateUrl : "red.htm",
        controller : "redCtrl"
    })
    .when("/green", {
        templateUrl : "green.htm",
        controller : "greenCtrl"
    })
    .when("/blue", {
        templateUrl : "blue.htm",
        controller : "blueCtrl"
    });
});
```

In each controller, you can set the data to be loaded in the corresponding templates.

For more information refer these links

- https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_views.htm

Comment: Yes i am using these configuration only  , but still when i press back or redirect like window.location="#/page.html" it is redirecting but the previous page data like table , some div elements are coming.when i reload its loading the perfectly the valid current page data

Comment: I think it should be window.location="#page", not window.location="#/page.html"

Comment: You can also use something like arc-reactor for a template router [by url-hash]: https://github.com/vishva8kumara/arc-reactor.

There you can even attach a function that receives additional parameters by url-hash, and define enter/exit transition animations by class names.